# Error detection and reporting using Maybe

Tags: parsing, haskell, text-parsing

I am writing a propositional logic parser in Haskell. I am doing the parsing by hand for now as a learning exercise. Eventually I will tackle Parsec. In the mean time, I am trying to wrap my head around Monads. In particular, I am using `Maybe` to report errors from my `parse` function. My current trouble is with part of a helper function:

```
parse' :: String -> (Maybe Wff, String)
parse' ('[':rest) = (x, if null rest''
                        then ""
                        else tail rest'')
        where (a, rest') = parse' rest
              (b, rest'') = parse' (if null rest'
                                    then ""
                                    else tail rest')
              x = if null rest'
                     || null rest''
                     || head rest' /= '|'
                     || head rest'' /= ']'
                  then Nothing
                  else Or <$> a <*> b
```

(For reference, the full `parse` function can be found [here](https://github.com/codeguru42/theorem/blob/2efca7ec42752e64ac60377f0e815d99bd695e14/Wff.hs).)

This code parses a proposition of the form `[ A | B ]` where `A` and `B` are any arbitrary propositions. As you can see, I am using applicative style on the last line to propagate the `Nothing` result if a previous recursive call results in a `Nothing`. This allowed me to take out `a == Nothing` and `b == Nothing` from the `if` condition. How can I use the `Applicative` or `Monad` instance of `Maybe` to colapse the rest of this `if`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a function from `Control.Monad` called `guard`. This has a slightly odd type:

```
guard :: MonadPlus m => Bool -> m ()
```

`MonadPlus` covers all monads that have some "empty" case. For lists, this is `[]`; for `Maybe` it is `Nothing`. `guard` takes a boolean; if it is `False`, it evaluates to this empty value; otherwise it evaluates to `return ()`. This behavior is mostly useful in `do` notation:

```
x = do guard (not $ null rest' || null rest'' || head rest' /= '|' || head rest'' /= ']')
       Or <$> a <*> b
```

What happens here is simple. If the condition evaluates to `True`, guard returns `Just ()`, which is then ignored in favor of `Or <$> a <*> b` (since that's how `do` notation works). However, if the condition is `False`, `guard` returns `Nothing`, which propagates through the rest of the `do` notation to give you an end result of `Nothing`: exactly what you wanted.

To make the code more readable, I would also pull the condition out into its own variable in a `where` block.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will look into `guard` a little bit more. One question/comment: I see that you negated my original condition with `not`. I think this is because you are reversing the logic of my `if` expression, right? That makes sense...I think...I need to think it through a bit more.

Comment: Yeah. `guard True` doesn't do anything while `guard False` results in `Nothing` (or whatever your monads "zero" value is).

Comment: Thanks. If you have time, check out my next question, which you sparked with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056881/monoid-vs-monadplus

Answer (score 5):

I will actually do the problem backwards: I will begin from the monadic solution and work backwards from it to the hand-rolled solution.  This will produce the same code that you would get if you arrived at the correct solution by hand.

The typical type signature of a monadic parser is of the form:

```
type Parser a = String -> Maybe (a, String)
```

Notice the slight difference with your form, where you have the final `String` on the outside of the `Maybe`.  Both are valid, but I prefer this form more because I consider the leftovers `String` invalid if the parse failed.

This type is actually a special case of `StateT`, which is defined as:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a, s) }
```

Notice that if we choose:

```
s = String
m = Maybe
```

... we get back the `Parser` type:

```
type Parser a = StateT String Maybe a

-- or: type Parser = StateT String Maybe
```

What's cool about this is that we only need to define one parser by hand, which is the parser that retrieves a single character:

```
anyChar :: Parser Char
anyChar = StateT $ \str -> case str of
    []   -> Nothing
    c:cs -> Just (c, cs)
```

Notice that if we removed the `StateT` wrapper, the type of `anyChar` would be:

```
anyChar :: String -> Maybe (Char, String)
```

When we wrap it in `StateT` it becomes:

```
anyChar :: StateT String Maybe Char
```

... which is just `Parser Char`.

Once we have that primitive parser, we can define all the other parsers using `StateT`'s `Monad` interface.  For example, let's define a parser that matches a single character:

```
import Control.Monad

char :: Char -> Parser ()
char c' = do
    c <- anyChar
    guard (c == c')
```

That was easy!  `guard` requires a `MonadPlus` instance for our monad, but we already have one.  The reason why is thanks to the following two `MonadPlus` instances:

```
instance (MonadPlus m) => MonadPlus (StateT s m) where ...

instance MonadPlus Maybe where ...
```

The combination of these two instances means that `StateT s Maybe` automatically implements `MonadPlus`, so we can use `guard` and it will just magically do "the right thing".

With those two parser in hand, your final parser becomes very easy to write:

```
data Wff = Or Char Char deriving (Show)

parseWff :: Parser Wff
parseWff = do
    char '['
    a <- anyChar
    char '|'
    b <- anyChar
    char ']'
    return (Or a b)
```

That's much clearer and easier to understand what is going on.  It also works:

```
>>> runStateT parseWff "[A|B]"
Just (Or 'A' 'B',"")
```

## Working Backwards

This brings us to your original question: How do you hand-write the same behavior?  We will work backwards from the `Monad` and `MonadPlus` instances to deduce what they are doing under the hood for us.

To do this, we must deduce what the `Monad` and `MonadPlus` instances for `StateT` reduce to when its base monad is `Maybe`.  Let's begin from the `Monad` instance for `StateT`:

```
instance (Monad m) => Monad (StateT s m) where
    return r = StateT (\s -> return (r, s))

    m >>= f  = StateT $ \s0 -> do
        (a, s1) <- runStateT m s0
        runStateT (f a) s1
```

Notice that it is defined in generically terms of the base monad.  This means we also need the `Monad` instance for `Maybe` to derive what the above code does:

```
instance Monad Maybe where
    return  = Just

    m >>= f = case m of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just a  -> f a
```

If we substitute the `Maybe` monad instance into the `StateT` monad instance we get:

```
instance Monad (StateT s Maybe) where
    return r = StateT (\s -> Just (r, s))

    m >>= f  = StateT $ \s0 -> case runStateT m s0 of
        Nothing      -> Nothing
        Just (a, s1) -> runStateT (f a) s1
```

We can do the same thing to derive the `Monad` instance for `StateT s Maybe`.  We just have to take the `MonadPlus` instances for `StateT` and `Maybe:

```
instance (MonadPlus m) => MonadPlus (StateT s m) where
    mzero = StateT (\_ -> mzero)
    mplus (StateT f) (StateT g) = StateT (\s -> mplus (f s) (g s))

instance MonadPlus Maybe where
    mzero = Nothing
    mplus m1 m2 = case m1 of
        Just a  -> Just a
        Nothing -> case m2 of
            Just b  -> Just b
            Nothing -> Nothing
```

... and combine them into one:

```
instance MonadPlus (StateT s Maybe) where
    mzero = StateT (\_ -> Nothing)
    mplus (StateT f) (StateT g) = StateT $ \s -> case f s of
        Just a  -> Just a
        Nothing -> case g s of
            Just b  -> Just b
            Nothing -> Nothing
```

Now we can derive what our parsers are doing under the hood.  Let's begin with the `char` parser:

```
char c' = do
    c <- anyChar
    guard (c == c')
```

This desugars to:

```
char c' = anyChar >>= \c -> guard (c == c')
```

We just derived what `(>>=)` does for `StateT s Maybe`, so lets substitute that in:

```
char c' = StateT $ \str0 -> case runStateT anyChar str0 of
        Nothing      -> Nothing
        Just (a, str1) -> runStateT ((\c -> guard (c == c')) a) str1
```

We already know the definition of `anyChar`, so let's substitute that in:

```
char c' = StateT $ \str0 -> case runStateT (StateT $ \str -> case str of
        []   -> Nothing
        c:cs -> Just (c, cs) ) str0 of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just (a, str1) -> runStateT ((\c -> guard (c == c')) a) str1
```

We also know that `runStateT` is the inverse of `StateT`, so:

```
char c' = StateT $ \str0 -> case (\str -> case str of
        []   -> Nothing
        c:cs -> Just (c, cs) ) str0 of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just (a, str1) -> runStateT ((\c -> guard (c == c')) a) str1
```

We can then apply the lambda to `str0`:

```
char c' = StateT $ \str0 -> case (case str0 of
        []   -> Nothing
        c:cs -> Just (c, cs) ) of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just (a, str1) -> runStateT ((\c -> guard (c == c')) a) str1
```

Now we distribute the outer case statement over the inner case statement:

```
char c' = StateT $ \str0 -> case str0 of
    []   -> case Nothing of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just (a, str1) -> runStateT ((\c -> guard (c == c')) a) str1
    c:cs -> case Just (c, cs) of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just (a, str1) -> runStateT ((\c -> guard (c == c')) a) str1
```

... and evaluate the case statements:

```
char c' = StateT $ \str0 -> case str0 of
    []   -> Nothing
    c:cs -> runStateT ((\c -> guard (c == c')) c) cs
```

Then we can apply the lambda to `c`:

```
char c' = StateT $ \str0 -> case str0 of
    []   -> Nothing
    c:cs -> runStateT (guard (c == c')) cs
```

To simplify that further, we need to know what `guard` does.  Here is the source code for it:

```
guard pred = if pred then return () else mzero
```

We already know what `return` and `mzero` for `StateT s Maybe` are, so let's substitute them in:

```
guard pred = if pred then StateT (\s -> Just ((), s)) else StateT (\_ -> Nothing)
```

Now we can inline that into our function:

```
char c' = StateT $ \str0 -> case str0 of
    []   -> Nothing
    c:cs -> runStateT (if (c == c')
        then StateT (\s -> Just ((), s))
        else StateT (\_ -> Nothing) ) cs
```

If we distribute `runStateT` over that we get:

```
char c' = StateT $ \str0 -> case str0 of
    []   -> Nothing
    c:cs -> (if (c == c')
        then (\s -> Just ((), s))
        else (\_ -> Nothing) ) cs
```

Similarly, we can apply both branches to `cs`:

```
char c' = StateT $ \str0 -> case str0 of
    []   -> Nothing
    c:cs -> if (c == c') then Just ((), cs)  else Nothing
```

That's the equivalent code we would have written by hand had we not used the `Monad` or `MonadPlus` instances at all.

## The Final Parser

I will now repeat this process for the last function, but leave the derivation as an exercise for you:

```
parseWff = do
    char '['
    a <- anyChar
    char '|'
    b <- anyChar
    char ']'
    return (Or a b)

parseWff = StateT $ \str0 -> case str0 of
    []     -> Nothing
    c1:str1 -> if (c1 == '[')
        then case str1 of
            []      -> Nothing
            c2:str2 -> case str2 of
                []      -> Nothing
                c3:str3 -> if (c3 == '|')
                    then case str3 of
                        []      -> Nothing
                        c4:str4 -> case str4 of
                            []      -> Nothing
                            c5:str5 -> if (c5 == ']')
                                then Just (Or c2 c4, str5)
                                else Nothing
                    else Nothing
        else Nothing
```

... but we can further simplify that to:

```
parseWff = StateT $ \str0 -> case str0 of
    '[':c2:'|':c4:']':str5 -> Just (Or c2 c4, str5)
    _                      -> Nothing
```

Notice that, unlike the function you wrote, this doesn't use any partial functions like `tail` or incomplete pattern matches.  Also, the code you wrote doesn't compile, but even if it did, it would still give the wrong behavior.

Comment: "the code you wrote doesn't compile, but even if it did, it would still give the wrong behavior." Other than missing the definition of `Wff`, what doesn't compile in the code I gave? And can you provide an example input that would give the wrong behavior?

Comment: @Code-Guru I figured out the issue.  It's because you don't have a base case for parsing the elementary propositions (i.e. `A` and `B`), so I mistakenly assumed that you were storing `Char`s in the `Wff` type.

Comment: Using `Char` is a reasonable simplification for the current discussion. My apologies for over-simplifying the code that I originally posted. I added a link to the corresponding version in my github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [answer by @TikhonJelvis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056075/error-detection-and-reporting-using-maybe/17056563#17056563), I revamped my whole `parse` function. (The `parse'` function from the OP is in the `where` clause of `parse`.) The first revision uses do notation and `guard

```
parse :: String -> Maybe Wff
parse s = do
  (x, rest) <- parse' s
  guard $ null rest
  Just x
    where  parse' ('~':rest) = do
             guard . not $ null rest
             (a, rest') <- parse' rest
             Just (Not a, rest')
           parse' ('[':rest) = do
             guard . not $ null rest
             (a, rest') <- parse' rest
             guard . not $ null rest'
             guard $ head rest' == '|'
             (b, rest'') <- parse' $ tail rest'
             guard . not $ null rest''
             guard $ head rest'' == ']'
             Just (a `Or` b, tail rest'')
           parse' (c:rest) = do
             guard $ isLower c
             Just (Var c, rest)
           parse' [] = Nothing
```

Some further experimentation helped me figure out that I can replace all but one of the uses of `guard` with direct pattern matching:

```
parse :: String -> Maybe Wff
parse s = do
  (x, "") <- parse' s
  Just x
    where  parse' ('~':rest) = do
             (a, rest') <- parse' rest
             Just (Not a, rest')
           parse' ('[':rest) = do
             (a, ('|':rest')) <- parse' rest
             (b, (']':rest'')) <- parse' rest'
             Just (a `Or` b, rest'')
           parse' (c:rest) = do
             guard $ isLower c
             Just (Var c, rest)
           parse' [] = Nothing
```