# Monoid vs MonadPlus

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass, monoids, monadplus

I am very new to both `Monads` and `Monoids` and recently also learned about `MonadPlus`. From what I see, `Monoid` and `MonadPlus` both provide a type with a associative binary operation and an identity. (I'd call this a semigroup in mathematical parlance.) So what is the difference between `Monoid` and `MonadPlus`?

Comment: A [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) is a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) *without* an identity--they're different things. In practice, I've found monoids to be far more common in programming than semigroups, but there is a nice [semigroups](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.9.2) package you can use if you do need those.

Comment: Also see Matt Fenwick's question ["Confused by the meaning of the 'Alternative' type class and its relationship to other type classes"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13080606/237428) (full disclosure: which I answered).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) is a structure equipped with an associative binary operation. A [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) is a semigroup with an identity element for the binary operation.

## Monads and semigroups

Every monad has to adhere to [the monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws). For our case, the important one is the associativity law. Expressed using `>>=`:

```
(m >>= f) >>= g     ≡   m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
```

Now let's apply this law to deduce the associativity for `>> :: m a -> m b -> m b`:

```
(m >> n) >> p       ≡ (m >>= \_ -> n) >>= \_ -> p
                    ≡ m >>= (\x -> (\_ -> n) x >>= \_ -> p)
                    ≡ m >>= (\x -> n >>= \_ -> p)
                    ≡ m >>= (\x -> n >> p)
                    ≡ m >> (n >> p)
```

(where we picked `x` so that it doesn't appear in `m`, `n` or `p`).

If we specialize `>>` to the type `m a -> m a -> m a` (substituting `b` for `a`), we see that **for any type `a` the operation `>>` forms a semigroup on `m a`.** Since it's true for any `a`, we get a class of semigroups indexed by `a`. However, they are not monoids in general - we don't have an identity element for `>>`.

## MonadPlus and monoids

`MonadPlus` adds two more operations, `mplus` and `mzero`. [`MonadPlus` laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monadplus) state explicitly that `mplus` and `mzero` must form a monoid on `m a` for an arbitrary `a`. So again, we get a class of monoids indexed by `a`.

Note the difference between `MonadPlus` and `Monoid`: `Monoid` says that some single type satisfies the monoidal rules, while `MonadPlus` says that for all possible `a` the type `m a` satisfies the monoidal laws. This is a much stronger condition.

So a `MonadPlus` instance forms two different algebraic structures: A class of semigroups with `>>` and a class of monoids with `mplus` and `mzero`. (This is not something uncommon, for example the set of natural numbers greater than zero `{1,2,...}` forms a semigroup with `+` and a monoid with `×` and `1`.)

Comment: So `MonadPlus` with `mplus` is also a semigroup, right?

Comment: @Code-Guru Exactly - any monoid is also a semigroup, if we drop the identity element.

Comment: Isn't `(a->m a)` with `>=>` also a monoid, with identity `return`?

Comment: @Hjulle For a fixed `a` it is, as a [moniod can be viewed as a category with a single object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Relation_to_category_theory).

Comment: Isn't `+` a monoid in natural numbers with `0` ?

Comment: @Fresheyeball Yes, natural numbers with 0 and + form a monoid, while positive natural numbers with + only form a semigroup, but positive naturals with * and 1 form a monoid. (To be exact, it's not 100% precise to say that "+ is a monoid" - an algebraic structure must be always given as a set and all its operations.)

Answer (score 12):

If we have that `MonadPlus m` holds then you'd say `m` is a `Monad`, but `m a` (the type resulting from applying `a` to the type "function" `m`) is a monoid.

If we define (similar to `Data.Monoid`'s definition, but we'll make use of this later)

```
class                Semigroup a where  (<>) :: a -> a -> a
class Semigroup a => Monoid    a where  zero :: a
```

then it has

```
mzero :: MonadPlus m => m a
mplus :: MonadPlus m => m a -> m a -> m a
```

with pretty comparable types and the apropriate laws

```
-- left and right identity
mplus a     mzero   ==   a
mplus mzero a       ==   a

-- associativity
(a `mplus` b) `mplus` c   ==   a `mplus` (b `mplus` c)
```

We can even define a Haskell `Monoid` if we use `-XFlexibleInstances`

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
instance MonadPlus m => Semigroup (m a) where  (<>) = mplus
instance MonadPlus m => Monoid    (m a) where  zero = mzero
```

though these overlap badly with the instances in `Data.Monoid`, which is probably why it isn't a standard instance.

---

Another example of a monoid like this is `Alternative m => m a` from `Control.Applicative`.

Comment: `MonadPlus` has some laws that interact with `Monad`; e.g. ``(a `mplus` b) >>= f = (a >>= f) `mplus` (b >>= f)``.

Comment: Re the overlap with `Data.Monoid`: this is exactly what I was confused by. Why isn't it automatically the case that `forall a. MonadPlus m => Monoid (m a)`? If we weren't worried about backwards compatibility, and could assume `-XFlexibleInstances`, then is there any further reason for that not to automatically hold?

Comment: @dubiousjim Consider this:```Just "a" `mappend` Just "b" == Just "ab"```, ```Just "a" `mplus` Just "b" == Just "a"```

Answer (score 7):

I must stress the very important difference: unlike Monoid, and unlike what the other answers state, MonadPlus does **not** provide a type with an associate binary operation and the identity. Haskell Report, the only document that can claim the status of the Standard, does not specify the laws of MonadPlus and hence does not require mplus to be associative or mzero
to be its left or right unit. Perhaps the authors were still debating the laws: there are very good reasons for mplus to be not associative. For example, if mplus is associative but non-commutative, the non-deterministic search computation represented by MonadPlus cannot be complete (that is, there exist solutions we cannot find). Since it is quite rare that mplus is commutative, any complete non-deterministic search procedure cannot be represented by MonadPlus, if we insist on the associativity. There has been a detailed discussion of this very issue of MonadPlus laws on SC: [Must mplus always be associative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722906/must-mplus-always-be-associative-haskell-wiki-vs-oleg-kiselyov)