# Why MonadPlus and not Monad + Monoid?

Tags: haskell, monads, monoids, monadplus

I'm trying to understand the motivation behind the `MonadPlus`. Why is it necessary if there are already the typeclasses `Monad` and `Monoid`?

Granted, instances of `Monoid` are concrete types, whereas instances of `Monad` require a single type parameter. (See [Monoid vs MonadPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056881/monoid-vs-monadplus) for a helpful explanation.) But couldn't you rewrite any type constraint of

```
(MonadPlus m) => ...
```

as a combination of `Monad` and `Monoid`?

```
(Monad m, Monoid (m a)) => ...
```

Take the `guard` function from `Control.Monad`, for example. Its implementation is:

```
guard :: (MonadPlus m) => Bool -> m ()
guard True = return ()
guard False = mzero
```

I was able to implement it using only `Monad` and `Monoid`:

```
guard' :: (Monad m, Monoid (m ())) => Bool -> m ()
guard' True = return ()
guard' False = mempty
```

Could someone please clarify the real difference between `MonadPlus` and `Monad` + `Monoid`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> But couldn't you rewrite any type constraint of
>
> ```
> (MonadPlus m) => ...
> ```
>
> as a combination of Monad and Monoid?

No. In the top answer to the question you link, there is already a good explanation about the laws of MonadPlus vs. Monoid. But there are differences even if we ignore the typeclass laws.

`Monoid (m a) => ...` means that `m a` has to be a monoid for one particular `a` chosen by the caller, but `MonadPlus m` means that `m a` has to be a monoid for all `a`. So `MonadPlus a` is more flexible, and this flexibility is helpful in four situations:

1. If we don't want to tell the caller what `a` we intend to use.
   `MonadPlus m => ...` instead of `Monoid (m SecretType) => ...`
2. If we want to use multiple different `a`.
   `MonadPlus m => ...` instead of `(Monoid (m Type1), Monoid (m Type2), ...) => ...`
3. If we want to use infinitely many different `a`.
   `MonadPlus m => ...` instead of not possible.
4. If we don't know what `a` we need.
   `MonadPlus m => ...` instead of not possible.

Comment: If you would not mind, I would really like to see a concrete example here. Can you provide some instances using specific Monads where MonadPlus is more useful or cleaner than Monoid?

Comment: @Fresheyeball: No, I canot provide "some instances using specific Monads", sorry. If the monad is known, there is no need to abstract over m, and no need to use any type classes to specify the expected interface of m, so the difference between `MonadPlus` and `Monoid` doesn't really matter if your code only works with one particular monad.

Comment: I understand that. But its hard to conceptualize the practice without seeing how specific monads would work with generalized code.

Answer (score 6):

Your `guard'` does not match your `Monoid m a` type.

If you mean `Monoid (m a)`, then you need to define what `mempty` is for `m ()`. Once you've done that, you've defined a `MonadPlus`.

In other words, `MonadPlus` defines two opeartions: `mzero` and `mplus` satisfying two rules: `mzero` is neutral with respect to `mplus`, and `mplus` is associative. This satisfies the definition of a `Monoid` so that `mzero` is `mempty` and `mplus` is `mappend`.

The difference is that `MonadPlus m` is a monoid `m a` for any `a`, but `Monoid m` defines a monoid only for `m`. Your `guard'` works because you only needed `m` to be a `Monoid` only for `()`. But `MonadPlus` is stronger, it claims `m a` to be a monoid for any `a`.

Answer (score 5):

With [the `QuantifiedConstraints` language extension](http://i.cs.hku.hk/%7Ebruno//papers/hs2017.pdf) you can  express that the `Monoid (m a)` instance has to be uniform across all choices of `a`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}

class (Monad m, forall a. Monoid (m a)) => MonadPlus m

mzero :: (MonadPlus m) => m a
mzero = mempty

mplus :: (MonadPlus m) => m a -> m a -> m a
mplus = mappend
```

`Alternative`ly, we can implement the "real" `MonadPlus` class generically for all such monoid-monads:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, DerivingStrategies, QuantifiedConstraints #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative

newtype MonoidMonad m a = MonoidMonad{ runMonoidMonad :: m a }
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

instance (Applicative m, forall a. Monoid (m a)) => Alternative (MonoidMonad m) where
    empty = MonoidMonad mempty
    (MonoidMonad x) <|> (MonoidMonad y) = MonoidMonad (x <> y)

instance (Monad m, forall a. Monoid (m a)) => MonadPlus (MonoidMonad m)
```

Note that depending on your choice of `m`, this may or may not give you the `MonadPlus` you expect; for example, `MonoidMonad []` is really the same as `[]`; but for `Maybe`, the `Monoid` instance lifts some underlying semigroup by artifically giving it an identity element, whereas the `MonadPlus` instance is left-biased choice; and so we have to use `MonoidMonad First` instead of `MonoidMonad Maybe` to get the right instance.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** So the lightbulb turned on, and everything clicked into place. I completely misinterpreted Toxaris's answer. Now that I understand, I've nothing to add except some supporting examples, and an observation that the `Alternative` and `Monad` constraints seem unnecessary in the `MonadPlus` type class definition.

```
monadPlusExample :: (MonadPlus m) => m Int
monadPlusExample = do
  x <- idM 7
  f <- idM (* 6)
  return $ f x
  where
    idM a = return a `mplus` mzero

-- a Monoid constraint for each lifted type
monoidExample :: (Monad m, Monoid (m Int), Monoid (m (Int -> Int))) => m Int
monoidExample = do
  x <- idM 7
  f <- idM (* 6)
  return $ f x
  where
    idM a = return a <> mempty

-- yes, QualifiedConstraints unifies the Monoid constraint quite nicely
monoidExample2 :: (Monad m, forall a. Monoid (m a)) => m Int
monoidExample2 = do
  x <- idM 7
  f <- idM (* 6)
  return $ f x
  where
    idM a = return a <> mempty
```

In order to be called, they have to be typed with a concrete type (e.g. `monoidExample2 :: [Int]`)

Comment: With the fairly new `QuantifiedConstraints` extension, you can write a constraint like `(Monad m, forall a. Monoid (m a))`. Without that extension, using just `Monoid (m a)`, you could run into problems with polymorphic recursion. Lots of things turn out to matter when you need polymorphic recursion!

Comment: The need for extensions in order to get a number type classes working correctly is a whole other topic...

Comment: Most of those extensions are perfectly fine. `QuantifiedConstraints` is still a little rough around the edges. But I really think your answer here is missing my point. Suppose you have something like `data Foo m a = Stop [m a] | Go (Foo m (a, a))`. Now imagine that for whatever reason you need to be able to combine elements of the list in the `Stop` constructor. Unless you use `QuantifiedConstraints`, there is no way to give a `Monoid` constraint that will let you do that—you'll need something like `MonadPlus`. Is `QuantifiedConstraints` a game changer? Well, we'll see; it's too new.

Comment: My issue isn't with the extensions themselves. It's with the type classes' need for them.

Comment: @Sledge I don't understand why your issue with type classes that need extensions is relevant here. `(Monad m, Monoid (m a))` is not quite equivalent to `MonadPlus m` because the former can be satisfied by a caller in a way that depends on the specific `a`, and the latter can't (and neither of those situations is *better* than the other, they're just different). With `QuantifiedConstraints` there is a *different* constraint using `Monad` + `Monoid` we now can write that is closer to `MonadPlus` equivalence, but none of the classes we've been talking about need any extensions to work correctly.

Comment: @Ben Purely tangential. When type classes and extensions are mentioned in the same context, I'm reminded of type classes like `MonadState` and Parsec's `Stream` that require multiple extensions to make them work. However, as you implied, that's not the case here, hence my comment of "a whole other topic."