# What can we do with Alternative but cannot do with Monoid?

Tags: haskell, monads, monoids, alternative-functor, monadplus

I read [Why MonadPlus and not Monad + Monoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023961/why-monadplus-and-not-monad-monoid) and I understand a theoretical difference, but I cannot figure out a practical difference, because for List it looks the same.

```
mappend [1] [2] == [1] <|> [2]
```

Yes. Maybe has different implementations

```
mappend (Just "a") (Just "b") /= (Just "a") <|> (Just "b")
```

But we can implement Maybe Monoid in the same way as Alternative

```
instance Monoid (Maybe a) where
  Nothing `mappend` m = m
  m `mappend` _ = m
```

So, can someone show the code example which explains a practical difference between Alternative and Monoid?

The question is not a duplicate of [Why MonadPlus and not Monad + Monoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023961/why-monadplus-and-not-monad-monoid)

Comment: Ahm... sorry, but this is still a duplicate. Toxaris [listed quite clearly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23024217/745903) what you can't do with `Monoid`, in particular points 3. and 4.: “**3.** If we want to use infinitely many different `a`.`MonadPlus m => ...` instead of not possible. **4.** If we don't know what `a` we need. `MonadPlus m => ...` instead of not possible.” If something about that isn't clear to you, please ask specifically about your doubts.

Comment: It's just theoretical explanation. Even there the first comment was " I would really like to see a concrete example here". I want practical code examples which can show how exactly 3 and 4 affect monoid usage.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. By I don't think it's helpful to cook up some contrived examples – sure, for small examples we could give here you can always say _“now why don't we just expose that private data type abstractly”_ or _“those are a couple of `Monoid (f A), Monoid (f B)` constraints, but so what? – it doesn't look that bad”_ or _“why don't we put those infinitely many / unknown types in an existential/GADT wrapper”_. But all these workarounds aren't really practical in a big project. Just look up some library functions with `Alternative` context, and try to write them with `Monoid`.

Comment: Have you deleted the closed question and posted it again? Please avoid that, it is really confusing.

Comment: @duplode It was marked as duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why MonadPlus and not Monad + Monoid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023961/why-monadplus-and-not-monad-monoid)

Comment: @phadej No one can write a simple code example which will show the difference, but everyone think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023961/why-monadplus-and-not-monad-monoid is answer to the question.

Comment: @ais Please don't delete a question just because it was closed. Instead, either rally to get it reopened, or ask a fresh question (as you did here) and reference it, explaining _exactly_ what makes the fresh question different. I think you gave a good explanation of what makes this question different. But hiding the history of the question is a bit underhanded, and may rub people the wrong way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of something one can do with `Alternative`:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Foldable

data Nested f a = Leaf a | Branch (Nested f (f a))

flatten :: (Foldable f, Alternative f) => Nested f a -> f a
flatten (Leaf x) = pure x
flatten (Branch b) = asum (flatten b)
```

Now let's try the same thing with `Monoid`:

```
flattenMonoid :: (Foldable f, Applicative f) => Nested f a -> f a
flattenMonoid (Leaf x) = pure x
flattenMonoid (Branch b) = fold (flattenMonoid b)
```

Of course, this doesn't compile, because in `fold (flattenMonoid b)` we need to know that the flattening produces a container with elements that are an instance of `Monoid`. So let's add that to the context:

```
flattenMonoid :: (Foldable f, Applicative f, Monoid (f a)) => Nested f a -> f a
flattenMonoid (Leaf x) = pure x
flattenMonoid (Branch b) = fold (flattenMonoid b)
```

Ah, but now we have a problem, because we can't satisfy the context of the recursive call, which demands `Monoid (f (f a))`. So let's add that to the context:

```
flattenMonoid :: (Foldable f, Applicative f, Monoid (f a), Monoid (f (f a))) => Nested f a -> f a
flattenMonoid (Leaf x) = pure x
flattenMonoid (Branch b) = fold (flattenMonoid b)
```

Well, that just makes the problem worse, since now the recursive call demands even more stuff, namely `Monoid (f (f (f a)))`...

It would be cool if we could write

```
flattenMonoid :: ((forall a. Monoid a => Monoid (f a)), Foldable f, Applicative f, Monoid (f a)) => Nested f a -> f a
```

or even just

```
flattenMonoid :: ((forall a. Monoid (f a)), Foldable f, Applicative f) => Nested f a -> f a
```

and we can: instead of writing `forall a. Monoid (f a)`, we write `Alternative f`. (We can write a typeclass that expresses the first, easier-to-satisfy constraint, as well.)